# How to map another keycode for back navigation in AOSP 13?

Tags: android, android-source, android-framelayout

I am using AOSP 13 source code.

- To do back via adb shell

---

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

4 is key code for back

I want to map back navigation via key code 141, so that i can use above command for back as

```
adb shell input keyevent 141
```

Is that possible ?

Comment: As per Android's Keyevent.java keyevent 141 is mapped to the F11 key internally. You could still override the keyevent, check for 141 and inject a back event.
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-13.0.0_r69:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java;bpv=0#:~:text=int%20KEYCODE_F11%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3D-,141,-%3B

Comment: @RajatGupta    I want to apply it for whole system not for any specific application can you please give some details how can I over ride the keyevent, which specific files I have to look into AOSP source? I have looked into PhoneWindowManager.java and found all key events handled from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

- As the keycode 141 is mapped to KEYCODE_F11 in frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java
- Need to handle  input event for KEYCODE_F11 in frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/PhoneWindowManager.java
- Import files

> ```
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.os.SystemClock;
> import android.view.InputEvent;
> import android.view.KeyEvent;
> import com.android.server.LocalServices;
> import com.android.server.input.InputManagerService;
> import android.hardware.input.InputManager;
> ```

- In function interceptKeyBeforeQueueing() there is a swhitch case added the case for KEYCODE_F11 in it.

```js
// Handle special keys.
         switch (keyCode) {
+           case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F11:
+               long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
+               if (down)
+               {
+                       // Inject a key down event
+                       KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, 0);
+                       InputManager.getInstance().injectInputEvent(downEvent, InputManager.INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_FINISH);
+               }
+               else
+               {
+                       // inject a key up event
+                       KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, 0);
+                       InputManager.getInstance().injectInputEvent(upEvent, InputManager.INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_FINISH);
+               }
+               break;
             case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK: {
                 if (down) {
                     mBackKeyHandled = false;
```